# Breakpoint on mobile window with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, media-queries

How can I add a breakpoint when viewing the HTML content in a small window (eg xs)?

```
<br class="show-when-small-window">
```

Comment: use @media queries

Comment: Can you elaborate or give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suggest this hack but use @media queries to achieve your goal. `hi` is just for showing purpose that its working or not

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .show-when-small-window {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="show-when-small-window">
hi <br>
</span>
```

**BOOTSTRAP**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<span class="d-none d-sm-block">
hi <br> hi
</span>
```

More information: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/display/

Comment: Isn't there a built in method instead of me writing that class?

Comment: if you are using, bootstrap than its `d-none d-sm-block`

Comment: Why the block? Isnt that removing it?

Comment: d-none means its uses `display: none` in all resolution but when you using `d-sm-block` means its change CSS property when breakpoint reaches `567px` and convert into `display: block`

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap-4 `scss`

```
.show-when-small-window{
    display: none;
    @include media-breakpoint-down(xs){
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Pure CSS

```
.show-when-small-window{
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 575.98px){
    .show-when-small-window{
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Using Bootstrap-4 utility

```
<br class="show-when-small-window d-inline d-sm-none" />
<!-- or -->
<br class="show-when-small-window d-inline d-md-none" />
<!-- or -->
<br class="show-when-small-window d-inline d-lg-none" />
<!-- or -->
<br class="show-when-small-window d-inline d-xl-none" />
```

> Note: `<br />` display will be `inline`.

Comment: yeh, you can use SCSS here but OP tag for CSS and for using bootstrap mixins, you need to import SCSS files, so please specify it else that mixin not work

Answer (score 1):

To show an element only on a given interval of screen sizes you can combine one .d-*-none class with a .d-*-* class, for example .d-none .d-md-block .d-xl-none will hide the element for all screen sizes except on medium and large devices.
[image]

[Change the value of the display property with our responsive display utility classes.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/display/)